# Pi Matching circut for tube PA - what values?

Tags: impedance, transmitter, amplifier, antenna-tuner, vacuum-tubes

I am working on my 80m and 40m CW transmitter and ran into a problem:

I need to match the high impedance of PL504 to 50ohm coax, a Pi match seems to be the best, but I don't know how to calculate the inductor - the calculators online give capacitor values of several nF, too big for tuning caps and sometimes they just say NaN.

Operation class is C and I'd like to get 20W of power at least.

- What is the best value for plate RF choke?
- Can it be made with a SMPS power core rated for 200kHz?
- Are there any general errors?

[image: schematic]

Comment: What frequencies are we talking about?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ah yes, forgot about it, 3.5MHz and 7Mhz.

Comment: Hm, in that case, a core rated for 200 kHz will probably not work very well, will it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Even as a RFC?

Comment: oh wait, sorry, I mixed that up and thought it was the inductor in your $\Pi$ matcher

Comment: @MarcusMüller So what value RFC and the other coil?

Comment: Generally, you'd want infinite value for your plate choke – any high-frequency current leaking into the 200 V supply is forever gone and can't reach the antenna. I'm having a hard time guestimating the output impedance of this amplifier (but maybe, just maybe a bit of leakage is intended, so to filter out the harmonics), so I can't tell you how to build a matching circuit.

Comment: Maybe output impedance is RFC impedance at a given frequency in 0

Comment: that doesn't make sense. The ideal impedance of a choke at frequency 0 is 0.

Comment: I posted accidentally, In parallel to plate resistance, so for 100uH RFC at 3.5MHz and plate resistance of 5k output impedance should be around 2.5k

Comment: I honestly don't know – not versed enough in tube amplifiers. If I knew, I'd already have posted an answer!

Comment: https://home.sandiego.edu/~ekim/e194rfs01/jwmatcher/matcher2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspection of figures 17.17 through 17.19 in the ARRL *Handbook* suggest that the components in your Pi network might need to be adjusted:

[image]

Jim Tonne, W4ENE, wrote a utility called [PIEL](http://tonnesoftware.com/piel.html) to calculate output tank values. A Pi-L network - a Pi network with an L-network extension - is frequently used to match a wider range of impedances than a Pi network alone can handle.

To use the program, you must know the load represented by the plate of the tube. PIEL includes a "Plate load help" button to perform this calculation using your intended voltage swing, RMS output power and class of operation.

Assuming you want the plate to swing over half the 100V supply to produce 20W in class C, PIEL calculates the plate impedance to be 62.5$\Omega$. Entering this value in PIEL's main screen with an intermediate impedance of 50$\Omega$ to drop the L-section yields this Pi network:

[image]

Increasing the plate voltage swing and reducing the network Q reduces the capacitor values. You can experiment with these values until you find a network you can build with available components. For example, increasing the swing to 90V and reducing the Q to 3 produces this network:

[image]

But, you need to keep in mind that the network may no longer provide the harmonic rejection required to comply with FCC rules.

Comment: Which one --if any-- has the correct pi-network values for the OP's circuit?

Comment: @MikeWaters It depends on the OP's goals: e.g., willingness to change design, need to use components on hand, harmonic attenuation provided by added networks (antenna matching unit), etc. This is a significant engineering question with a lot of "knobs" to turn.

Comment: @BrianK1LI I want to use components at hand, I have 4 section 330pF, 360pF, 2x 15pF tuning caps, I also wind my own coils. I could use a diffrent design if it means I can use these tjning caps. The tuning section will be the part of a QRP 20W TX, shown in the OP.

Comment: @BrianK1LI Also - can I increase the inductance (to let's say, 8uH) and use slightly smaller capacitors? BTW. My call sign is SO9LEK

Comment: @thegamebusterpl I just added your call to [your profile](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/14961/thegamebusterpl?tab=profile). You can edit that if you like. :-)

Comment: @MikeWaters Aw thanks, didn't know I could add my call there!

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: I offer these results only as a *possible* solution. Completing this design may depend on many other factors, thermal and electrical, steady state and transient, component- and layout-dependent parasitics. This is the subject of, at least, sizeable chapters if not entire text books, which I will not reproduce here. Your mileage may vary.

I entered the following values into the PiEl program:

Plate load help:

```
- Plate voltage swing: 190 volts
- RF power: 12 watts, RMS
- Class C (k=2)
```

- Plate load result: 1.504k ohms

Main page

```
- Frequency: 3.5MHz
- Plate load: 1.504k
- Intermediate impedance: 1.504k
- Load impedance: 50 ohms
- Pi-section Q: 10
```

Resulting output network:
[image]

Resulting harmonic output:
[image]

You can do this yourself to settle on a set of parameters that best meets your particular constraints and requirements.